# Getting the index of pandas dataframe for matching row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have to dataframes in pandas , `A` and `B`:

A:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({0:[1.24, 8.75, 4.32]})

0    1.24
1    8.75
2    4.32
```

where the `0 1 2 3 4 5` is the index of the dataframe

and another dataframe with strings as index:

```
B = pd.DataFrame({0:[9.43, 1.24, 9.09, 4.32, 8.85]}, index=['p_32','p_21','p_01','p_05','p_76'])

'p_32'    9.43
'p_21'    1.24
'p_01'    9.09
'p_05'    4.32
'p_76'    8.75
```

All of the numbers in the first column of `A` are contained in `B` but not the other way around. I want to get the index strings of `B` whos row number matches `A`, while retaining the order that in `A`

So I would need:

```
'p_21'
'p_76'
'p_05'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function for that:

```
In [141]: B[B[0].isin(A[0])].index
Out[141]: Index(['p_21', 'p_05', 'p_76'], dtype='object')

In [142]: B[B[0].isin(A[0])]
Out[142]:
         0
p_21  1.24
p_05  4.32
p_76  8.75
```

data:

```
In [139]: A
Out[139]:
      0
0  1.24
1  8.75
2  4.32

In [140]: B
Out[140]:
         0
p_32  9.43
p_21  1.24
p_01  9.09
p_05  4.32
p_76  8.75
```

Comment: I originally thought of this, but it doesn't answer the requirement of maintaining the same order as in A

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this program by using a join operation. First, use `reset_index` on B to make the index a new column in the dataframe. Then use an inner join to combine the two dataframes together using the `merge` function. Make sure you disable sorting during the join operation. The index column in the new dataframe will have what you want.

Here is the pandas documentation on joins http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging